# Ionic page not passing data from transcript to HTML

Tags: ionic3

I am reading json data from an api via a provider and then listing the data successfully.

The code below is from my **paper.html** how I list and call a click function for each item:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let paper of papers" (click)='loadPaper(paper)'>
    {{paper.paper.title}}
</ion-item>
```

The **loadPaper()** function, below, is implemented in **paper.ts**:

```
loadPaper(paper){
    console.log('A paper', paper);
    this.navCtrl.push(this.loadPaperPage, {paper:paper});
  }
```

At this point, *console.log* successfully shows the data content of one entry from the json. I also push the paper data to another page, *loadPaperPage*.

My problem is in **load-paper.html**: when I try to print data from the passed *paper* object, I get the following error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'paper'
>   of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'paper' of undefined
>       at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ng:///AppModule/LoadPaperPage.ngfactory.js:32:31)
>       at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:15067:21)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14181:14)
>       at callViewAction (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14527:21)
>       at execComponentViewsAction (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14459:13)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14182:5)
>       at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:15430:42)
>       at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14967:12)
>       at ViewRef_.detectChanges (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:11951:22)
>       at NavControllerBase._viewAttachToDOM (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:52404:40)
>       at c (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19752)
>       at Object.reject (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19174)
>       at NavControllerBase._fireError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:52167:16)
>       at NavControllerBase._failed (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:52160:14)
>       at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:52207:59
>       at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14976)
>       at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:5123:33)
>       at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14916)
>       at r.run (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10143)
>       at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:20242

My paper object does not seem to exist and I'm not sure why exactly.

**load-paper.html** follows:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>loadPaper</ion-title>
    TEST: {{paper.paper.title}}
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
</ion-content>
```

And, load-paper.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

/**
 * Generated class for the LoadPaperPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-load-paper',
  templateUrl: 'load-paper.html',
})
export class LoadPaperPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoadPaperPage');
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you please add the most relevant parts of the `load-paper.html` and `load-paper.ts` files?

Comment: @sebaferreras: I've added the code

Comment: @sisko i will solve the problem. paper is a object and how many element of this object

Comment: @Utpaul: There are 6 objects in the json but onclick should only pass a single object

Comment: @sisko are you checked it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that sending the parameter is not enough, you also need to get it in the page where you want to use it. So this should work:

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-load-paper',
  templateUrl: 'load-paper.html',
})
export class LoadPaperPage {

  public paperParam: any; // Property to get the param

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoadPaperPage');

    // Get the parameter sent and put it in the paperParam
    // property from this component so you can use it in the view
    this.paperParam = this.navParams.get('paper');
  }

}
```

And then in the view, use that new `paperParam` property:

```
<ion-header>    
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>loadPaper</ion-title>        
  </ion-navbar>    
</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

  <!-- Now you can use the paperParam property from the component -->
  TEST: {{ paperParam.paper.title }}

</ion-content>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a try asap

Comment: @sebaferreras i remove it

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped @sisko :)